# C# Html.ValidationMessageFor not working when form post

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have an issue with validation messages.

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult Others(string bid)
    {
              return View(ret);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult OthersUser(Others info)
    {
             return RedirectToAction("Others", "User", new { bid = "1" });
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult OthersPass(Others info)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
          
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Others", "User", new { bid = "2" }); ;
    }
```

Password Confirm Class:

```
public class PassConfirm
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
    public virtual int UserID { get; set; }
    public string Key { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "Passwords not matching!")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}
```

Others Class:

```
public class Others
{
    public int BID { get; set; }

    public PassConfirm PassChg { get; set; }
    public String OldPsw { get; set; }

    public User User { get; set; }
    public string UserCheck { get; set; }


}
```

View:

```
<div style="display: flex; align-items: center;">
            @using (Html.BeginForm("OthersPass", "User", FormMethod.Post))
            {
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label for="oldpsw">Eski Şifre:</label></td>
                        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.OldPsw ,new { @id = "oldpsw", @type = "password" })</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label for="newpsw">Yeni Şifre:</label></td>
                        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.PassChg.Password, new { @id = "newpsw", @type = "password" })</td>
                        <td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.PassChg.Password)</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label for="confpsw">Şifreyi Doğrula:</label></td>
                        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.PassChg.ConfirmPassword, new { @id = "confpsw", @type = "password"})</td>
                        <td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.PassChg.ConfirmPassword)</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <button class="btn btn-success" formmethod="post">Onayla</button>
            }
        </div>
```

When the user clicked the button with the wrong values, it returns nothing. I think the problem is caused by 2 post method. Maybe because of the values ​​returned by ActionResult elements. So what could be the source of the problem?

Comment: "When the user clicked the button with the wrong values, it returns nothing". What nothing? Values or validation errors?  But what happens when the user clickes the button with correct values? Do you get a password values?

Comment: "I think the problem is caused by 2 post method." - try to use just one metod and let us know.

Comment: Normally, I wrote Debug.WriteLine("IT HAPPENED"); into ModelState.IsValid block. So, it returns "IT HAPPENED".

Comment: You have to check if it posts the values.

Comment: I checked all post values and there is no problem. Just error messages not working.

Comment: First you can try to make the entire `@Html.ValidationSummary` to see if the message of you model state is ok. You can try to not redefine ids of input, i prefer use @Html.DisplayFor with associated [Display(...)] attribute inside your view model

Comment: Have you added the `Javascript` validation plugins in order after `Jquery` ?

Comment: Ok, thanks to @Orkad. ValidationSummary is better than ValidationMessage. I tried to return with View("Others", info) and it worked. So, the problem is RedirectToAction method.

Comment: Sounds like you're sorted, but just in case. My understanding is, the ModelState is cleared when you redirect to another action/url, so there are no errors to show. If you want to keep them, you'd need to adjust your action methods so your full object is posted back and then returned using the View(model) method. Or how ever you want to do it.